# Update query on in the collection by "_id"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongodb-update

```
{
    "_id" : "tenant/data/EMAIL/ENGLISH",
    "tenantId" : "tenant2",
    "channelType" : "EMAIL",

    "template" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "templateName" : "abc",
            "effectiveStartDate" : ISODate("2017-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"),
            "modifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-02T22:08:55.782Z"),
            "active" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update the `"templateName" : "xyz"` on the basis of `"_id" : "tenant/data/EMAIL/ENGLISH"`

I have tried these queries but got no success

```
db.getCollection('data').updateOne({"_id": "tenant/data/EMAIL/ENGLISH"},
                     {$set : { "template.$.templateName" : "XYZ"}}); 

db.getCollection('data').updateOne({"_id": "tenant/data/EMAIL/ENGLISH"},

                     {$set : { "template.templateName" : "XYZ"}});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `template` array field has only one object ? If yes then you can use `$` otherwise you need to specify filter something like `template._id : 1` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [positional-all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator to update the array.

Here is the query:

```
db.sample.update(
  {
    "_id": "tenant/data/EMAIL/ENGLISH"
  },
  {
    $set:{
      "template.$[].templateName":"XYZ"
    }
  }
)
```

**Output**

```
{
        "_id" : "tenant/data/EMAIL/ENGLISH",
        "tenantId" : "tenant2",
        "channelType" : "EMAIL",
        "template" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "1",
                        "templateName" : "XYZ",
                        "effectiveStartDate" : ISODate("2017-01-01T12:00:00Z"),
                        "modifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-02T22:08:55.782Z"),
                        "active" : false
                }
        ]
}
```

hope this will help :)